# C++ constexpr realization differencies

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, constexpr, clang++

Just learnt about *constexpr* functions and went to *godbolt* to know how compiler optimize code and found out, that compilers act quite differently.

Have the following code:

```
constexpr int square(int num) {
    return num * num;
}

int main() {
    int a = square(2);
}
```

*g++* and *icc* compilers calculate function result and assign it to a variable (as I expected), but *msvc* and *clang* call function.

To use optimization we should make additional step:

```
constexpr int square(int num) {
    return num * num;
}

int main() {
    constexpr int c = square(2);
    int a = c;
}
```

Is there any reasonable explanation of such behavior?

Link to godbolt example: https://godbolt.org/z/ez7luu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All compilers are correct.

A `constexpr` function is a function that can be computed compile-time or run-time, according to the circumstances.

Pretending there isn't the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), we can say that the compiler **must** compute compile-time when the result of a `constexpr` function goes somewhere where is requested to be known compile time.

By example, the size of an array

```
int  a[square(10)];
```

or a template parameter

```
std::array<int, square(10)>  a;
```

or a `constexpr` variable

```
constexpr int  a { square(10) };
```

There are circumstances where the function **must** be computed run-time, as when receive run-time known input values; by example

```
int a;

std::cin >> a;

int b { square(a) };
```

Otherwise the compiler can choose if compute the value compile-time or run-time.

In your first version

```
int a = square(2);
```

we are in the compiler-can-choose area, because `2` is known compile-time, so the compiler can choose the compile-time computation, but the value is requested for a not `constexpr` variable, so a compile-time value isn't necessary.

And you see that two compilers are computing compile-time and two others run-time. Generally, this kind of behavior heavily depends on the optimization level. In fact, all compilers produce a different output [after adding `-O2`](https://godbolt.org/z/hGw8rR) to the compile flags in your example.

In your second version

```
 constexpr int c = square(2);
```

the `square()` value is requested for a `constexpr` variable, so all compilers **must** compute `square(2)` compile-time (and they can do it, because `2` is a value known compile-time).